# Group by Month displaying duplicate months in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, transactions, group-by

I have a table that logs transactions for a Warehouse DB. Amongst the information in this table is the location the transaction occurred to, the date the transaction ended, the time it ended, the qty transferred, and the Division. I am trying to get :
- No of Units and transactions per month per Division like this :

`Division  Month   Transactions     Units

1         January   5                10
1         February  10               11
2         February   5               10`

My SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT  tranl.Division, 
    DATENAME(month,tranl.trandate) AS 'Month',
    COUNT(tranl.qty) AS Transactions,
    SUM(tranl.qty) AS Units
FROM translog (nolock) tranl 
WHERE tranl.location = 'stage' 
AND end_tran_date >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY end_tran_date, tranl.Division
ORDER BY  tranl.Division
```

but I got a different result:

`Division       Month      Transactions       Units
1             January        5                 10
1             January        3                 22
2             February      10                 40
2             February       3                 12
2             March          1                  1
....`

Comment: can you give the sql to create the DW table and maybe a few sample rows too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're grouping by end_tran_date, but you want to group by just the month part of that date.  The following will potentially work:

```
select 
    DISTINCT  tranl.Division, 
    DATENAME(month,tranl.trandate) as 'Month',
     COUNT(tranl.qty) as TRANSACTIONS,
     SUM(tranl.qty) as UNITS
    from translog (nolock) tranl 
    where tranl.location = 'stage' 
   and end_tran_date >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000' 
   GROUP BY DATENAME(month,tranl.trandate), tranl.Division
   ORDER BY  tranl.Division
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause needs to specify that data should be grouped by month **and likely year** (although you don't specify, I'm assuming you don't want transactions for different years to be aggregated):

## SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT tranl.division,
    FORMAT(end_tran_date, 'yyyy-MM', 'en-us') AS Month,
    Count(tranl.qty) AS Transactions,
    Sum(tranl.qty) AS Units     
FROM
    translog (nolock) tranl      
WHERE
    tranl.location = 'stage'             
    AND end_tran_date >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000'      
GROUP  BY
    tranl.division,
    FORMAT(end_tran_date, 'yyyy-MM', 'en-us')      
ORDER  BY
    tranl.division
```

## SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT tranl.division,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), end_tran_date, 120) AS Month,
    Count(tranl.qty) AS Transactions,
    Sum(tranl.qty) AS Units     
FROM
    translog (nolock) tranl      
WHERE
    tranl.location = 'stage'             
    AND end_tran_date >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00.000'      
GROUP  BY
    tranl.division,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), end_tran_date, 120)      
ORDER  BY
    tranl.division
```

If available to you, I think the SQL Server 2012 syntax using `FORMAT` is easier to read than the cryptic `CONVERT` syntax for formatting dates.

Comment: this worked as well, just had to play around with the format, thanks!